# Get the UItableViewCell Contentview Programmettically using the section and index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to get the specific uitableviewcell contentview using the row and index of the cell in the tableview?

I tried the below code but it is not working:

```
NSIndexPath *nowIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNo inSection:sectionNo];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];
```

Comment: Will this cell be visible when you are trying to get the content view or is there the possibility that it will be off the screen?

Comment: Your code should Work fine. What you getting from this code ? nil ?

Comment: @Deeps: I am getting nil, that is the only problem

Comment: Where did you write this code ? I meant in which method ?

Comment: @Deeps: I have a tableview with grid of subviews in each cell. whenever the user is selecting any one of the grid I am having one gesture recognizer in that place i am using this code

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [`cellForRowAtIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a),

> An object representing a cell of the
>   table or nil if the cell is not
>   visible or indexPath is out of range.

It's likely that the cell at `nowIndex` isn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's a better way to do what you're trying to do. Since you're obviously loading the content of the cell from *somewhere* why not just access that?

i.e. If you're trying to get the state of a cell subview, you should have that object in your class header (not just instantiated in cellForRowInIndexPath). Then you can access the value from anywhere within the class.